# Add queue model on processMessage method of channel

Tags: queue, message-queue, omnet++, inet

I am trying to add a queueing model (M/D/1) on the channel on the processMessage method but the problem in queueing model that I have to send selfmessage which is not supported by cchaneel class? so how can I make processMessage work as cSimpleModule class ( which allows sending selfmessage to it self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT queue messages inside a channel, just as in real world, packets are not queued on your ethernet cable while a transmission is in progress. Instead, the sending node's network interface *knows* when the transmission will finish and the network interface itself queues up the extra messages until the wire gets free.  So the queue should be in the network interface card (which is a module). See the routing example that does exactly this:

https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/samples/routing/node/L2Queue.cc

Comment: thank you so much, what about if I used Output Queues such as DropTailQueue and FIFOQueue form Inet Framework which is added between mac and network layer ? is that similar to what you have mentioned?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that's why network interfaces in INET are also implemented this way.

Comment: If you think this answers your question, 'accept' it so other users will benefit, too.